# Creating use with passport while logged in with passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to have it so a user can login and then create clients (another sub user) with passport. I have the main user accounts working but I can not get the client accounts to work.

I need the sessions to be set to false, I tried the same code before I put that in and it failed on the `serialize user` part of passport. It is saving the client user data to the database but it crashing the server.

Please ask if you have questions or I need to add something to thew post.

This is the error message I get when I go to sign them up:

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
_http_outgoing.js:356
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at done (/home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1004:10)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:565:9
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/asset-management/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:690:9
    at tryToString (fs.js:456:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:443:12)
```

**MY ROUTE**

```
app.post('/dashboard/client/new',
    setRedirect({auth: '/client/dashboard', success: '/dashboard/client/new', failure: '/dashboard/client/new'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    registrations.postClientSignup);
```

**postClientSignup**

```
exports.postClientSignup = function(req, res, next){
  req.assert('email', 'Please sign up with a valid email.').isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 6 characters long').len(6);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    req.flash('form', {
      email: req.body.email
    });
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
  // calls next middleware to authenticate with passport
  passport.authenticate('clientSignup', {
    session: false,
    successRedirect: '/dashboard/client/new', // Select redirect for post signup
    failureRedirect: '/dashboard/client/new',
    failureFlash : true
  })(req, res, next);
    next();
};
```

**PASSPORT CODE**

```
passport.use('clientSignup', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      var findOrCreateUser = function(){
        Client.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          if (existingUser) {
            req.flash('form', {
              email: req.body.email
            });
            return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'An account with that email address already exists.'));
          }
          // edit this portion to accept other properties when creating a user.
          var user = new Client({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password, // user schema pre save task hashes this password
            bizID: req.body.bizID,
            role: req.body.role
          });
          console.log(req.body.email);
          console.log(req.body.password);
          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return done(err, false, req.flash('error', 'Error saving user.'));
            var time = 14 * 24 * 3600000;
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = time; //2 weeks
            req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + time);
            req.session.touch();
            return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.'));
          });
        });
      };

      process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);

    })
```

**ALSO IN PASSPORT**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```